# Mysql field type for </textarea>?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mysql field type "tinytext" and am using performing and update via my form with following extract:

```
<!-- Text input
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="myinput"> Input code</label> 
  <div class="controls"> 
<textarea class="form-control" id="myinput" name="myinput"  rows="4" ><?php echo $myinput;?> </textarea> 
 </div>
</div>
```

However the field is not recieving the data properly.
What mysql field type do I use for a textarea of about 4 lines?

Comment: `<textarea>` does NOT have a type. Oh, and nor does it have a "value", should you want to use that too.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it's "not receiving the data properly"?

Comment: Use `text` for `<textarea>`

Comment: The `<!--` is an html comment, maybe that is your issue?

Comment: The field contains the embed code for a youtube video. It displays ok, with a select statement, but when I try to use UPDATE it does not write to the field.

Comment: and no mysql to boot.  The ***less*** the good people know, the ***more time*** it takes to provide you with a solution.

Comment: Use text for <textarea> – Nana Partykar was the right answer.

Comment: How do I award the answer to Nana Partykar?

Comment: What? How is `<textarea>` the answer? You have that already... This question is going all sorts of different ways. Also no idea what you are talking about with `select` and `update` that is server side..

Comment: I mention MySQL in the question, and quote HTML code from my form. My question was which type of MySQL field to hold a value from a HTML textarea. Therefore "Use text for <textarea>", seems quite an obvious answer.

Comment: @NanaPartykar question is all yours. Good luck..

Comment: By changing the MySQL field to type text, it accepted data from the HTML textarea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
TINYTEXT - 256 bytes
TEXT - 65,535 bytes
MEDIUMTEXT - 16,777,215 bytes
LONGTEXT - 4,294,967,295 bytes
```

As OP clearly mentioned "*..field is not recieving the data properly.*" And, need to insert 4 lines in `<textarea>`. So, from my side `text` field type should be used for `myinput` textarea.

For more info, Please click [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use `text` data type, when storing text.

As I don't know what do you mean with "not receiving data properly", you should also process user input in your backend, to store it as you need (for example, if it has multiple lines, you can replace them with `\n` or `<br />` if you want to output data later).